# Groovy multiline string keep new line and indentation

Tags: string, groovy, scripting, special-characters

If we have a multiline string in groovy, like this:

```
def multilineString = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipiscing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
"""
```

then using a simple `println multilineString;` will give an output for each line on a new line. Like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I would like groovy to OUTPUT in the following format, keeping all the new line characters `'\n'`, potentially tab characters `'\t'` and the indentation.

Desired output is a string on a single line that looks as follows:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\n        consectetur adipiscing elit,\n        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt\nut labore et dolore magna aliqua.`

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Completely new to groovy scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an approach like `println multilineString.replaceAll('\n', '\\\\n')`